# How to use different config files for different environments in airflow?

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I'm using `SparkKubernetesOperator` which has a template_field called application_file. Normally on giving this field a file's name, airflow reads that file and templates the jinja variable in it (just like script field in the BashOperator).

So this works and the file information is shown in the Rendered Template tab with the jinja variables replaced with the correct values.

```
start_streaming = SparkKubernetesOperator(
    task_id='start_streaming',
    namespace='spark',
    application_file='user_profiles_streaming_dev.yaml',
    ...
    dag=dag,
)
```

I want to use different files in the application_file field for different environments

So I used a jinja template in the field. But when I change the application_file with `user_profiles_streaming_{{ var.value.env }}.yaml`, the rendered output is just `user_profiles_streaming_dev.yaml` and not the file contents.

I know that recursive jinja variable replacement is not possible in airflow but I was wondering if there is any workaround for having different template files.

What I have tried -
I tried using a different operator and doing xcom push to read the file contents and sending it to SparkKubernetesOperator. While this was good for reading different files based on environment, it did not solve the issue of having the jinja variable replaced.

I also tried making a custom operator which inherits the SparkKubernetesOperator and has a template_field applicaton_file_name thinking that jinja replacement will take place 2 times, but this didn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an env file which had the environment details (dev/prod). Then I added this code to the start of my dag file

```
ENV = None
with open('/home/airflow/env', 'r') as env_file:
    value = env_file.read()
    if value == None or value == "":
        raise Exception("ENV FILE NOT PRESENT")
    ENV = value
```

and then accessed the environment in the code like this

```
submit_job = SparkKubernetesOperator(
    task_id='submit_job',
    namespace="spark",
    application_file=f"adhoc_{ENV}.yaml",
    do_xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

This way I could have separate dev and prod files.